# I cannot figure out how I created this file wrong

Tags: c, linux, file, system

I have been having trouble reading from a file I created in c with the creat system call. Here is the code:

```
XXXfid = creat ("XXX", 384);
    if (XXXfid<0) {printf("Error with creat"); return 0;}
    
        writeStatus = write (XXXfid, "limp", 4);
    if (writeStatus<0) {printf("error with write"); return 0;}
    lseek(XXXfid, 0, 0);
    
    readStatus = read(XXXfid, buffer, 120);
    if (readStatus<0) {printf("error with read2"); return 0;}
```

Every other command is working perfectly, I just can't read the file no matter what I try (ie closing and re-opening, etc). I have read and write permissions, do I need to give everyone read and write permissions? I wouldn't have thought so, given that the error I'm getting is 9- Bad File Descriptor. I'm at a total loss, any help would be appreciated
I believe in octal notation my permission would be 600. If it helps, this is 110 000 000 in binary and my ls -l confirms this is -rw- --- ---

Comment: Isn't this the same problem you posted earlier, except without the `creat()` call?

Comment: If you don't have permissions, `creat()` will fail.

Comment: Please use octal permissions. Few programmers can tell what permissions `384` is from sight.

Comment: `creat` opens the file for write-only.

Comment: @Barmar Yes! This is my attempt at properly providing minimal verifiable example- should I have done this differently? And what permissions are necessary for my program to read this file? I (the owner) have read/write, and I successfully wrote 'limp' so I guess I'm hoping you can elaborate?

Comment: `creat()` opens the file in write-only mode, you can't read from it.

Comment: @user3386109 Cool, any suggestions as to how I correct this?

Comment: When reporting the error, include `errno` and/or the output from `strerror(errno)`,  possibly by using `perror()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/creat.html):

```
creat(path, mode)
```

is equivalent to

```
open(path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode)
```

Notice that the flags contain `O_WRONLY`, not `O_RDWR`. This means you can only write to the file descriptor, not read from it.

If you want to read and write, use `open()` instead, with the appropriate flags.

```
XXXfid = open("XXX", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm definitely more in the weeds now given that I have not only been taught nothing about most of what I'm reading here, but also was explicitly told to use creat which everything I can find says is completely obsolete, but, hey, that's going 10's of thousands of dollars in debt for an education :). Please excuse the whining, this is definitely the answer and thank you for your patience and help

Comment: Most programs either read or write a file, it's unusual to read and write the same FD. `creat()` is for program that are just writing a file and need to create it first.